# Print 2D list as polynomial using Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use a 2D list as a method of storing a polynomial. I have been able to create an object that stores a 2D list, to represent the polynomial. However, I am having difficulty when I am trying to take the 2D list and display it in correct mathematical notation. This means that a list such as: `[[1,8],[-5,7],[-1,1],[-1,0]]` should have an output of: `x^8 - 5x^7 - x - 1`. Here is my program so far:

```
global poly
poly = []

class Polynomial():

    def __init__(self,num_list = []):
        sorted_list = list(sorted(num_list,key=(lambda d:d[1]),reverse=True))
        for i in sorted_list:
            poly.append(i)
        self.num_list = poly

    def display(self):
        for i in range(len(self.num_list)):
            for j in range(len(self.num_list[i])):
                print(self.num_list[i][j])

a = Polynomial([[1,8],[-5,7],[-1,1],[-1,0]])
a.display()
```

However, this program is only able to display each number from the list on a new line. I need to be able to display all the numbers on the same line, so I can include the variables and exponents.

Comment: You might consider overriding `__repr__` or `__str__`.  (probably `__str__`).  Build a string that looks the way you like, and return it from `__str__` and you will be able to do things like `print(a)` and it will display the way you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
class Polynomial():

    def __init__(self,num_list = []):
        sorted_list = list(sorted(num_list,key=(lambda d:d[1]),reverse=True))
        self.num_list = [i for i in sorted_list]

    def display(self):
        storage = []
        for i in range(len(self.num_list)):
            storage.append(str(self.num_list[i][0]) + 'x^' + str(self.num_list[i][1]))
        print(''.join(storage))

a = Polynomial([[1,8],[-5,7],[-1,1],[-1,0]])
a.display()
```

Output:

```
1x^8-5x^7-1x^1-1x^0
```

Obviously, there is some more advanced display logic you can play with, but I'll leave that up to you. Hope that helps!

Or if you want to throw the `display` functionality into a one-liner (updated from @bobrobbob's comment):

```
class Polynomial():

    def __init__(self,num_list = []):
        sorted_list = list(sorted(num_list,key=(lambda d:d[1]),reverse=True))
        self.num_list = [i for i in sorted_list]

    def display(self):
        print(''.join('%+dx^%d' % (a, b) if b!=0 else '%+d' % (a) for a, b in self.num_list))

a = Polynomial([[1,8],[-5,7],[-1,1],[-1,0]])
a.display()
```

Output:

```
+1x^8-5x^7-1x^1-1
```

Comment: Great! However, I tried it with a list such as [[-4,10],[1,7],[-1,3],[3,1],[1,0]], and I cannot figure out how to correctly display the addition/subtraction signs. It should appear as -4x^10 + x^7 - x^3 + 3x + 1.

Comment: As far as adding some deeper display logic, think about adding an `if` statement into the `display` method so that if the coefficient is a negative number then no leading `+` is added to the string, otherwise it is.

Comment: shorter one-liner `print(''.join('%sx^%s' % (a, b) for a, b in self.poly))` (and more readable)

Comment: @rahlf23 I tried that, however it still doesn't work. I also tried checking to check if the first character was a negative or a positive, and then add a + if necessary, but that didn't work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Update your post with your attempt and I can offer some suggestions.

Comment: I've got it working now. I have one last thing I need help with. If the exponent is a 0, then the variable should not be added. So if a list contains [[1,0]] it would be displayed as 1, rather than 1x^0.

Comment: Note that the coefficient associated with the last entry will always be the last element in your list. Use that to develop your logic.

Comment: @rahlf23 I tried using storage[-1:] == "0" however this checks the entire last index, so 1x^0, rather than just the 0.

Comment: @rahlf23 One last thing, if there is a 1 in front of an x, it shouldn't be displayed. Is there a way that this can be checked?

Comment: I'll have to leave that one to you. Perform a similar check to my updated answer.

Comment: @rahlf23 I know it should be something like "and a != 1" but I'm not sure how to format that into the line.

Comment: Break up the one-liner above into a structured for loop with separate `if`, `elif` statements. It will make more sense that way, plus you can account for more display conditions.

Comment: @rahlf23 Unfortunately I have no idea how to break it up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing problem in printing object in horizontal. if yes

change `print(self.num_list[i][j])` to

1. `print self.num_list[i][j],` in python 2
2. `print(self.num_list[i][j], end=" ")` in python 3

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, add `end = " "` to your print line and that should do the trick.

```
print(self.num_list[i][j], end=" ")
```

See [here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-without-newline-python/) Hope this helped!

Comment: This works for separating the numbers, however I still cannot figure out how to display the x^ part. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: print(str(self.num_list[i][0]) + 'x^' + str(self.num_list[i][1]) + end=" ") should do the trick